# Docker hub auto-build version and tag latest

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am using the Docker Hub automated build to build my updated image every time there is a new release on the associated GitHub repository.
A new release is automatically created (via CircleCI build) on any merge to master. That means I have 2 builds on Docker Hub every time I merge to master.
Is there a way within Docker Hub to build the release tag then automatically add the `latest` tag on it as well? That would save time.
Otherwise I need to add a web-hook or something to tag `latest` every times a release image is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this syntax : `latest,<tagname>`

This works on hub (ex: `latest,20.04`):

[Docker hub autobuild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIrys.png)

And produce a unique image:

[Docker hub tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNcM7.png)